# MySQL Difference between values yesterday and today

Tags: mysql

I know, it should be simple, yet I can't seem to find a solution or create one.

All I want to do is count the difference between dates.
So

5/2 and 5/01 = 4

5/1 and 4/30 = 5

etc.

[image]

This is what I got so far, but I wonder if because some of my rows don't have a value in them that is screwing things up....

```
SELECT g1.customer_count, (g2.customer_count - g1.customer_count) as DiffDaily 
from trux_customer_site_service_counts_max_df g1 
    inner join trux_customer_site_service_counts_max_df g2 
        on g2.Row_Number = g1.Row_Number +1 
where g1.customer_count is not null
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to achieve this?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I'm using a tool called Domo that has variance charts, but it isn't giving me the result i want.  I have built another table pulls out max counts for the date already, so this was the next step for me and I can't figure it out.

Comment: SELECT a.*,
@rank:=  IF(@prev = a.Count_Date2,@rank + 1,1) AS `Rank`
,@prev:= a.Count_Date2 AS Count_Date3

FROM (SELECT *, DATE(subdate(Count_Date, INTERVAL 4 hour)) AS Count_Date2
FROM trux_customer_site_service_counts
ORDER BY Count_Date) a , (SELECT @rank:=0, @prev:=NULL) b

Comment: b/c I thought that's what this community does and is for.

Comment: Hint: Self Join on "date of data"

Comment: This is what I got so far, but I wonder if because some of my rows don't have a value in them that is screwing things up....
SELECT


g1.customer_count,
(g2.customer_count - g1.customer_count) as DiffDaily


from trux_customer_site_service_counts_max_df g1
inner join trux_customer_site_service_counts_max_df g2  on g2.Row_Number  = g1.Row_Number +1

where g1.customer_count is not null

Comment: _NOTE:_ 1) You can edit your question with additional data. 2) Nobody can read code in a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do an inner join as illustrated below:

```
SELECT 
  A.DATE_OF_DATA `DD-1`, 
  DATE(B.DATE_OF_DATA) DD,
 (B.CUSTOMER_COUNT - A.CUSTOMER_COUNT) CUSTOMER_COUNT_DIFF
FROM 
 YOUR_TABLE A INNER JOIN YOUR_TABLE B
ON DATE(A.DATE_OF_DATA)=DATE(B.DATE_OF_DATA - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: That worked as well as what I did below but I still have to break it down into 2 steps because the way Domo I needed to create a new table that took out the nulls from the other table, and made row numbers that went in order and didn't jump from 1 to 12 etc Thank you

Answer (score 0):

thank you to Ankit who set me on my way.  Because I'm working in Domo MySQL you have to do things a little differently

```
SELECT 

trux_customer_site_service_counts_max_df.*
, @rownumber :=@rownumber +1 as RowNumber


from trux_customer_site_service_counts_max_df,
(select @rownumber :=0) as t
where customer_count is not null
```

Step 2

```
SELECT
g1.*,

(g2.customer_count - g1.customer_count) as DiffDaily


from customercount_no_nulls g1
inner join customercount_no_nulls g2  on g2.RowNumber  = g1.RowNumber +1
```